# some aspects of cocos2d not working with spritebuilder?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm fairly new to developing with apple and everything and I just recently got into spritebuilder (or formerly known cocosbuilder) There is this problem that is just boggling my mind.

From this line in XCode:

```
[_bird runAction:[CCSequence actions:bird_floatAnimation,nil];
```

when I type `CCSequence` just about anywhere I get `unknown reciever ccsequence, did you mean ccbsequence?` same thing with `CCRepeatForever`. Funny thing is that I can use `CCActionMoveTo` and `CCActionMoveBy` and run it and it works fine.

So what happened? This is driving me insane. I am using SpriteBuilder 1.0 with Cocos2d v3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is so simple! Found the answer [here on the spritebuilder forum](http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/xcode-doesnt-see-ccdirector-ccmoveby-etc/97)

To my misunderstanding and ignorance, since cocos2d v3, some of the classes and methods have been renamed so instead of `CCSequence` its `CCActionSeqence`..

amazing..